# Interesting Boot Order (MB Video Out)

Tags: boot, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, motherboard, gpu

I am looking for a better understanding of a certain behavior that is eluding me (the reasons for it, that is)

System Setup (for context)

- Sabertooth x58 MB (Triple channel setup)

  i7-960 OC

  GTX 950

  BlackMagic Intensity Pro (PCIe x1) -capture card

  GTX 560 Ti

  Windows 10

The interesting behavior comes in when I have both GPUs in use.
-(The 560 is used for Viewing monitor for streaming, Transcoding output, & preview, preventing resource drain on 950, allowing it to also drive a 1080p monitor for primary gaming, & a 4K TV @ 2-3k, for display reasons)

When I boot up my computer, if I have the preview display connected to my Capture card & both GPUs inserted, the MB errors out after attempting to use the capture card as a video out. 
– Though it does NOT have this behavior with 1 GPU, or an SLI setup (2xGTX 560ti)

I know the issue for me is minor, but anyone have an understanding of why an unpaired GPU would cause this behavior.  I know the MB prefers the top slotted GPU for booting towards with a connected display.

I have assumptions, but Help in understanding this would be valuable.

Comment: Does this error occur before or after the BIOS menu?

Comment: No Display is given, and the capture card display flickers a second.  The MB also doesn't turn off the 2nd light. (near the CPU, while the 1st is for the Ram/Speed/voltage/etc.)

So.. before, the BIOS menu. [I think]

Comment: This could be a number of things. To be completely honest, using three different devices, the number of compatibility issues are limitless. There could be issues between the cards and the board, the cards and each other, the capture device. IT's ultimately semi-impossible to determine which it is without ***direct*** access to the system itself :/

Comment: Fair enough, Though I know it's perfectly stable (requiring just to unplug the display for booting), while windows handles it as one would expect.  I'm not sure what to fully think, & my only assumption is that the different GPUs together confuse the MB and it sees the capture card as a output display.   Otherwise the system runs perfectly & better then expect now (where I couldn't use the TV as a display without problems before only using the 950)  Thank you though.  [Yes, I'd want to test if it's the same behavior if I had an AMD card instead of the 560]

Comment: The best of luck my friend! Do post an answer to your question if you ever find a definite answer ***;)***